# Is `scp` for non sudo users executable?

Tags: 14.04, server, sudo, files, scp

Can non sudo users execute `scp` command while using two remote servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. I never even have to use "sudo" with using "scp".

Mind though: as with all remote copy-ing the servers need to be setup to allow it. You can even use "scp" without having to use a user and without providing a password if you want.

Comment: How can i prevent `scp` asking password while transferring files among 2 remote servers.

Comment: With  ssh-key pairs. Example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182488/10017